# Database table design (User, Recipient, Address)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, database-design, database-schema

This is my first time posting at stack overflow. I'm having a lot of trouble modeling the following situation. Was hoping for some help.

Here are the business rules:

- User has a 0..1 to many relationship with Recipient (eg: a user can have zero or many recipients)
- User has a 0..1 to many relationship with Address (eg: a user can have zero or many addresses)
- Recipient has a 1 to 1 relationship with Address (eg: recipient must have an address)

This is what I have so far:

- User (UserID  PK)
- Recipient (RecipientID PK, UserID NOT NULL FK, AddressID NOT NULL FK)
- Address (AddressID PK, UserID NULL FK)

What really bothers me is that UserID in the Address table has to be nullable and I don't see any way around it.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: If UserID could be nullable then it should not have a relation on the address table. You can use a pivot table that would hold the relationship. Ex. UserAddressTable : ID, AddressID, UserID

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have built your design with "User" as the main entity,
but the scenario here requires "Address" to the main entity, so

```
Address (Aid PK)
Recipient (Rid PK, Aid not null FK)
User (Uid PK, Rid FK, Aid FK)
```

or

```
User (Uid, Rid, Aid) composite PK
```

Comment: this will just move the problem of a nullable foreign key fro the address table to the user table.

Answer (score 0):

As mehany wrote in his comment, you can add a relationship table between users and adresses:

```
UserAddresses 
(
    AddressId, -- FK to Address, UNIQUE.
    UserId -- FK to User
)
```

Comment: I was thinking the same but would that not make User and Address a many to many relationship...and is that ok? Thx.

Comment: I think making UserID unique would not make User have 0..1 to many relationship with Address...maybe you ment AddressID to be unique? Sorry if I sound not knowledgeable about this stuff.

Comment: Correct, the AddressId should be unique, sorry, my mistake.

Comment: If AddressId is unique in table UserAddress, doesn't it break this rule 'User has a 0..1 to many relationship with Address?

Comment: @JianHuang No, it doesn't. It means that every address will exists 0 or 1 times only in the table, while the users may exists in the table 0 or many times. that's exactly 0/1 to many.